# ImageView Max Size iOS MonoTouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am creating an image from a byte array using a UIImageView control. I need to ensure that the max size of the image is 600 x 600. How can I do that? I have tried SizeThatFits() and SizeToFit(), however, that just moves the image around on the screen. I have tried setting the Bound property to new RectangleF(0, 0, 600, 600), however, that also does no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check UIImage Size property for exceeding your limits. If so, [scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417969/resize-and-saving-an-image-to-disk-in-monotouch) it:

```cs
const int limit = 600;
if ((View.Frame.Size.Width > limit) || (View.Frame.Size.Height > limit))
{
    // Scale as on link above.
}
```

Alternatively, you could set Frame and ContentMode of your UIImageView to desirable values.