# Compress an iPhone image before upload

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, amazon-s3, xamarin

I have the following upload code, which is called after a users selects an image from their photo album:

```
public void Picked(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        picker.DismissViewController (false, null);

        image.Image = e.Info [UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;

        //get a stream of the image data
        imageData = image.Image.AsPNG().AsStream();
        filename = filenameBox.Text;

        spinner.StartAnimating ();

        Thread t = new Thread (UploadImage);
        t.Start ();
    }

    public void UploadImage()
    {
        //upload to s3
        Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client ("My access key", "my secret key");

        // Create a PutObject request
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest {
            BucketName = "my bucket name",
            Key = filename

        };


        //put the image data into the request
        request.InputStream = imageData;

         // Put image
        PutObjectResponse response = s3.PutObject(request);

        InvokeOnMainThread (StopSpinning);
    }
```

Everything works fine, but iPhone camera images have a large size and upload very slowly. I am looking for a way to easily compress the image before upload it to `s3`.

Ive read other questions that discussed a `scale` function coming out in monotouch? Is that the trick? How do I use it?

I am not looking to crop the image, just compress and reduce size. How can this be achieved?

I am looking for a `monotouch` example particularly rather than `objective c`

Comment: @Jason Is that `upcoming scale method` out?

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scale method of UIImage works well but it also reduces the size (in pixels) of the image. Depending on your requirements it may or may not suit you. Instead, you could experiment with the method UIImage.AsJPEG(float quality), where quality is between 0 and 1. This will reduce the quality of the image without changing the size in pixels.

Comment: This is perfect for my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

UIImage now supports a [Scale](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.Scale) method.  This is what Miguel was referring to in the [post you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417969/resize-and-saving-an-image-to-disk-in-monotouch).

Comment: Is there any example of how to use it? What exactly is `SizeF`?

Comment: SizeF is a width x height Struct